# Resign First Responder UITextView. Temporary UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

I am writing an application where I let the user edit some content in a text view, and I want to add a dismiss button, to let the user save there edits, without hacking around to dismiss the keyboard.

I am familiar with dismissing the keyboard programmatically and everything. The only real problem I have now, is a design problem. I want to let the user click a button just like in the notes app, but I don't have a UINavigationBar.

Is it possible to create a temporary Navigation bar and assign it a "done" button?

I am going to implement this in a custom UIView, so it should be controller independent. What I mean is I don't know if there is a UInavigationBar present in the current controller. So that must be dealt with dealt with before adding the temporary one.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One option would be to create a UIToolbar with your dismiss button and set it as the inputAccessoryView property of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work nicely for what you're describing:

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
UIToolbar *inputToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTapped)];
[inputToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton]];

self.theTextView.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar;
```

In `doneButtonTapped`

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: that's what I ended up with. Just with the button plaved to the right :)